# Is there a way to access the cookies that were sent with a request when using axios outside of the browser?

Tags: node.js, http, web-scraping, axios, fetch-api

Correct me if I am not understanding this correctly.

When the client makes a post request and has not sent any cookies, the server sends cookies back to it via the "set-cookie" parameter, and then the client sends them back to the server for subsequent requests.

Here's my issue. When analyzing requests via chrome developer tools, it appears as if the cookie header that is sent in the request header has more cookies in it than what was sent to the client in the **"set-cookie" response header.**

In order to validate some of my requests, **I need access to the full request cookie header** that has specific tokens that weren't included in the "set-cookie" response header.

Is there a way to access these cookies outside of the browser is a node environment** using axios or even fetch?**

Right now I have used the axios "headers" property to read the "set-cookie" values from the result of a post request.

There is also a "request" property, but I am unsure on how to access the cookie header from that request.

What knowledge am I missing here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment with setting the cookies, you can use an HTTP client like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or insomnia. These clients allow you to hit an endpoint and see the response in your case the body and headers.

There may be cases where you have a cookie stored on your browser from other websites; in that scenario, you should clear your cookies in the dev tools or go onto an incognito tab – but the same cane be done with the aforementioned http clients.